# Localhost refer to the machine where browser is or where the server

Tags: localhost, client-server

I have a scenario where my web application is running on my local server. When I get the application up it is through the URL:
http://localhost:8080/App. The application then posts some data to a different server which builds another request. My application needs this request, and the server tries to post the request to my application through URL: http://localhost:8080/App/data.

Question? Somehow this is not working, so I am wondering if the localhost refers to the machine where the browser is, or the server which is catering to the request?

Answer (score 0):

Reed about virtual host .
Or change your path of website project.

Comment: For your local , and use google for another one, there are a lot of infirmation